# Xsser command failing on fresh install

Tags: kali-linux

I'm running xsser and I'm getting the following error:

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'fuzzing/user-agents.txt'

This is a fresh install of Kali and I've tried to located the directory so I can manually import a list of user agents but I've had no luck locating it as the command only leads to /usr/bin/xsser which has no paths in the code. The only thing I can think of is xsser may be an installed pip package which is located somewhere in the file system.

Answer (score 0):

so
or you edit the /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xsser-YOUR-VERSION/core/curlcontrol.py on line 55 and put the full path to file user-agents.txt ( each time you change version you will have to edit this)

or depending from where you run the command , you create a folder fuzzing, and in this folder you put or create the user-agents.txt file

if you launch the command from /root/user  -> /root/user/fuzzing/user-agents.txt

of course the user-agents.txt should contain user-agent ^^

Comment: Could you clean up your answer? It is not easy to read

Answer (score 0):

```
# find / -name user-agents.txt #search for this file in your system
/root/xsser/core/fuzzing/user-agents.txt
^C #I stopped searching here, cause we just need this one file
root@kali:/# cd /root/xsser/core/ #get into directory
root@kali:~/xsser/core# xsser -u 'https://example.com' -p 'username=bob&password=XSS&captcha=X1S'
===========================================================================

XSSer v1.8[2]: "The Hiv3!" - (https://xsser.03c8.net) - 2010/2019 -> by psy

===========================================================================
(...)
```